# Validar somente números

Tags: javascript, regex

Preciso validar uma `string` usando `Expressão Regular`, ela só pode conter números. Então tentei usar a seguinte expressão `/[0-9]/`, mas se a `string` conter um caractere e um número é considerada válida.

```js
er = new RegExp(/[0-9]/);

document.getElementById("retorno").innerHTML = "" +
"s = " + Boolean(er.exec("s")) + "<br>" +
"s10 = " + Boolean(er.exec("s10")) + "<br>" +
"10 = " + Boolean(er.exec("10")) + "<br>" +
"10,0 = " + Boolean(er.exec("10,0")) + "<br>";
```

```html
<div id="retorno"></div>
```

OBS: Também já testei utilizando a expressão `/\d/` e o resultado foi o mesmo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tenta assim:

```
var valor = new RegExp('^[0-9]+$');
```

Nesse caso a resposta seria essa:
s = false
s10 = false
10 = true
10,0 = false

Para número flutuantes é usado ponto se por exemplo fosse usado 10.0, você pode usar dessa forma:

```
var valor = new RegExp(/^-?\d*\.?\d*$/);
```

Você tem o seguinte resultado:

s = false s10 = false 10 = true 10.0 = true

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou.